# SQLDescribeCol return negative value for a data type

Tags: mysql, odbc

```
//////////////////////////////////////
SQLTCHAR colName[256];
SQLSMALLINT colNameLen, dataType, numDecimalDigits, allowsNullValues;
SQLULEN columnSize;

rc = SQLDescribeCol ( hStmt, col, colName, 255, &colNameLen, &dataType, &columnSize, &numDecimalDigits, &allowsNullValues );

/////////////////////////////////////
```

I tried this code for mysql odbc driver and for a tiny int column it returns 0xfffa(-7) which does not correspond to any column type.

any help on this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-7 is SQL_BIT as in the following from sqlext.h:

`/usr/include/sqlext.h:#define SQL_BIT                                 (-7)`